# How to read in Modis MYDOCGA files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, import, hdf

I'm trying to import this file into Matlab, so that I can crop it: http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYDOCGA.006/2002.07.04/MYDOCGA.A2002185.h00v08.006.2015149042409.hdf

```
mypath='C:\Users\Desktop\';
fname='MYDOCGA.A2002185.h00v08.006.2015149042409.hdf';
Band8_Aqua=hdfread([mypath fname],'sur_refl_b08_c');
```

but it opens the file as a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: According to `hdfinfo`, your data is a vector (it appears that it was saved that way). You may be able to reconstruct it by looking through the other data or the info may be available from where you got/downloaded the file.

Comment: you can easily check and visualize the content of your hdf file with the nasa's seadas software https://seadas.gsfc.nasa.gov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to understand the data format and all of the other information in the file. I don't really know much about this area, but using [`hdftool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdftool.html), the following command was suggested:

```
frame = 'MYDOCGA.A2002185.h00v08.006.2015149042409.hdf';
sur_refl_b08_1 = hdfread(fname, 'MODIS_Grid_2D', 'Fields', 'sur_refl_b08_1');
```

Then `imshow(sur_refl_b08_1)` yields an image. You'll have to explore and learn more yourself. Check out [this page](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mydocga_v006), including the learning resources at the bottom.